# Printing a WebBrowser in a foreach loop

Tags: printing, browser

I have a collection of URLs in an arraylist. Now, I need to print the webpage in each URL using the `WebBrowser` control in my Windows Forms applcaition. Can anyone please help me out on how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1). Call IWebBrowser2.Navigate(..) to start loading a document.
2). Handle NavigateComplete() event. When the document is loaded you can print it: IHTMLDocument2.execCommand("print", null, null)

In the real world you need to handle errors, provide timeouts, as url can be wrond, server could be down etc.

Good luck!